# Kile or any TeX software cannot find 'TeX Live' binaries (manually installed) when launched from graphical menu or launcher icon

Tags: texlive, kile

I have recently installed latest `TeX Live 2020`. Post installation, I have added the `PATH` of `texlive` installation `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux` to  `~/.bashrc` and  `/etc/environment`. Now, if I start Kile from `terminal` it compiles any document using the installed `Tex Live 2020` binaries. Infact it can locate all the binaries. No error.

The problem starts when I run Kile from graphical menu or launcher icon. It just cannot find the LaTeX binaries anymore. Compiling a document gives an error: `<some-package>.sty` not found. Why does this happen?

P.S. There are lots of question asked on here, related to this particular topic. I have gone through almost all of the solutions (most of them talk about setting the correct `PATH`). I have done that. Rebooted the sytem too.

So I am raising this question (again!) with a hope for a fresh solution.

Comment: If Kile can start some LaTeX process that then doesn't find any packages (whereas a process started from the console can find all packages) that suggests you have a second TeX system on your machine that is found by Kile. I presume Kile has some configuration window to change its PATH settings. But see also https://sourceforge.net/p/kile/discussion/292014/thread/c1aa4881/. What does `which -a pdflatex` give on your machine? Does it list more than just the pdfLaTeX in `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux`?

Comment: @moewe `which -a pdflatex` lists more than one `pdfLaTex`, the other one being in `/usr/bin`. The issue is I can't remove the second TeX system as it removes Kile too. Also, the Kile doesn't have any configuration window where we can add the `PATH`.  I could find two ways in which KILE GUI can start LaTex process:  add `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux` to each TeX command in Kile GUI (see this https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-141934.html). The second way is to add `PATH` to `/etc/login.defs` (see https://github.com/latexdraw/latexdraw/issues/27#issuecomment-623427572).

Comment: Ah, yes Kile has a dependency on TeX live. You can install a fake TeX live package when you have a "vanilla" version from TUG in order to satisfy the dependencies. (See the fake packages section in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864.) If you found the solution, please write it down in the answer section below so other people can find it and benefit from it as well.

Comment: I will post the above comment as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For now I could solve the issue where Kile can find the `Tex Live 2020` binaries (manually installed) when it is run from graphical menu or launcher icon. I am listing the two solutions I found (links are provided below):

1. Open `Settings --> Configure Kile` window. Click on the menu `Build`. It will list all of the known TeX tools. For example, select `LaTeX`. Go to the `General` tab and add the texlive binaries `PATH` in command field to include `/latex`, which will then look like this: `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/latex`

The above steps are repeated for each of the TeX tools we use frequently.

Once all are done run `Settings --> System Check` to see if Kile executes the LaTeX processes from the `PATH` assigned.

(Step 1 is explained  in detail [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-141934.html)).

2. The second solution is to edit the file `/etc/login.defs`:

```
ENV_SUPATH  PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH  PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

This solution was suggested to me [here](https://github.com/latexdraw/latexdraw/issues/27#issuecomment-623427572) on raising a similar question for a TeX software (`LaTexDraw`). It too had similar issue like Kile.

I find Step 2 to work with any of TeX software (atleast for the two I have) where on starting it from graphical menu or launcher icon, it can locate all the latest LaTeX binaries.

Comment: I'd recommend the fake package solution over these, if only because it avoids needless software. But it also seems less likely to result in inadvertent changes or unwanted complications. But if you've done this fine for 3 years, it can't be a bad solution.